# Changes to method does not change view

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-backpack, php-7.3

I developed a function which creates a docx file using phpword template. This function saves a file on the server and auto downloads the file created to the user. One problem I've been noticing while testing it on the remote server is that any changes to the file don't reflect in the browser. I know, I've cleaned view, cache, config.. everything on the server and forced cache cleaning on the browsers(chrome, edge). Even deleted the files on resoures/framework/views when view:clear didn't do it. Enabled "Diasable cache" on Developer tools.

When I opened with a new browser it reflected the changes but after making some more and pressing ctrl + F5 everything stayed the same.

That function is on my employee crud controller and on my routes.php file is:

Custom.php

```
Route::get('employee/{id}/method', 'EmployeeCrudController@method');
```

EmployeeCudController.php

```
public function method($entry)
{... }
```

when I do this on local machine it works, but when I do it on the remote server it doesn't. The other routes work perfectly fine. Only the routes using "Route::get..." are suffering from this problem.

> Ex.
>
> 1. insert dd(['test1' => 'test1]);
> 2. access page of the controller. It shows what is supposed to.
> 3. alter dd(['test1' => 'test1]); to dd(['test1' => 'test1,'test2' => 'test2']);
> 4. ctrl + F5. still shows dd(['test1' => 'test1]);

I don't know what to do anymore.

Using Backpack 4.1 / Laravel 8.0 / PHP 7.3

Comment: Your `dd(['test1'...` example is likely to be significantly simpler to debug than the 3-stage file-generation-saving-and-downloading problem you lead with, so maybe focus on that.  When you say "*alter `dd(...)`*", what *exactly* do you do? How do you deploy the changes to your server? What OS is the server, and what is the web server? In you browser devtools, does the network request tab show the request is being cached? You mention you're clearing cache etc, are you running any of the `artisan cache` commands on the server, either generally, or as part of your deploy process?

Comment: i know, that's why i started introducing only dd(['test1'... . I use Cpanel to this minimal alterations on the files. The server is Linux CentOs 7. The network tab shows the call being made and on the preview tab it shows the dd() command. Any change i make besides this route (Route::crud.. ) works like intended. I've cheecked other Route::get i have on Custom.php route file, it happens to them too.

Comment: "*I use Cpanel to this minimal alterations on the files*" - what does this mean?  On the network tab, click the request, and look at the "general", "response headers", and "request headers" sections.  You should be able to tell if the response was cached, or any other relevant info.

Comment: an "add" was missing. "I use Cpanel to *add* minimal alterations on the files", it means i use the Cpanel File browser to open the file to add the dd() command. I've checked the general, response headers and request headers and it's not cached. This only happens when i click on the same entry, if i click on another entry i get the expected result for the first time.

Comment: Ex: click on another entry (second entry) to generate the file after making some changes to the server file, it works fine. make some more changes and then click on it again it doesn't refresh like the first entry. to get an updated response from the server file, i need to click on a third entry.